# Can Apache be set to recognise access to a folder an rewrite it to act the same as my vhost

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, virtualhost

I have a local test site set up as a vhost, 'http://site.local' which works fine, however now the rest of the company need to be able to look at it.

They can access my site at 'http://my.ip.add.ress/site'. Is there any way to make apache or htaccess recognise these outside connections and 'rewrite' them to act as if they were accessing 'site.local'

Asking them all to change host files etc is out of the question.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I created a _default_ vhost (`<VirtualHost _default_:*>`), and setup mod_proxy to forward all request to example.local. Poxying is probably overkill, but this way I could easily change it to show otherexample.local. It is on my work PC, and I'm currently have vacation. So I can provide actual code.

Comment: Is `site.local` and `my.ip.add.ress` different servers? Are they on different networks? Is `site.local` accessible from the internet or from `my.ip.add.ress`?

Comment: Thank you Gerben, I'll take a look into doing that.